# Number guessing program bug?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to create a number guessing program where the user inputs a number and the program tells you if your input is too high, too low, or correct. The program chooses a random number between 0-100. The problem is that when I start to test the program, when I choose 1, the program tells me that the guess is too high. But that is wrong since the program can only do whole numbers. And if the user inputted number does not equal the random number, 1 must be too low.
Can someone please look at my code and see if anything looks weird.

```
int guess;
    int guess2;
    int guess3;
    int guess4;
    int guess5;
    int random = (int)Math.random() * 100;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Try to guess a number between 0-100. You have five chances.");
    guess = input.nextInt();
    if(guess >= 100 || guess <= 0){
        System.out.println("Error, that is not a number between 0-100.");
    } else if(guess > random){
        System.out.println("The guess is too high.");
    } else if(guess < random){
        System.out.println("The guess is too low.");
    } else if(guess == random){
        System.out.println("YOU WIN");
    } else{
    }

    System.out.println("Second guess.");
    guess2 = input.nextInt();
    if(guess2 >= 100 || guess2 <= 0){
        System.out.println("Error, that is not a number between 0-100.");
    } else if(guess2 > random){
        System.out.println("The guess is too high.");
    } else if(guess2 < random){
        System.out.println("The guess is too low.");
    } else if(guess2 == random){
        System.out.println("YOU WIN");
    } else{
    }

    System.out.println("Third guess.");
    guess3 = input.nextInt();
    if(guess3 >= 100 || guess3 <= 0){
        System.out.println("Error, that is not a number between 0-100.");
    } else if(guess3 > random){
        System.out.println("The guess is too high.");
    } else if(guess3 < random){
        System.out.println("The guess is too low.");
    } else if(guess3 == random){
        System.out.println("YOU WIN");
    } else{
    }

    System.out.println("Fourth guess.");
    guess4 = input.nextInt();
    if(guess4 >= 100 || guess4 <= 0){
        System.out.println("Error, that is not a number between 0-100.");
    } else if(guess4 > random){
        System.out.println("The guess is too high.");
    } else if(guess4 < random){
        System.out.println("The guess is too low.");
    } else if(guess4 == random){
        System.out.println("YOU WIN");
    } else{
    }

    System.out.println("Last guess.");
    guess5 = input.nextInt();
    if(guess5 >= 100 || guess5 <= 0){
        System.out.println("Error, that is not a number between 0-100.");
    } else if(guess5 > random){
        System.out.println("The guess is too high.");
    } else if(guess5 < random){
        System.out.println("The guess is too low.");
    } else if(guess5 == random){
        System.out.println("YOU WIN");
    } else{
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks good, but you need to change the cast on this line:

```
int random = (int)Math.random() * 100;
```

to:

```
int random = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
```

Currently your random number is always 0.  Why?  Because you are casting Math.random() to an int, and in Java that means that everything after the decimal is lost.  (So, 0.85 would become 0.  0 * 100 = 0.)  By adding the parentheses we cast after Math.random() is multiplied by 100.

Also, note that your random number may be 0 but will never be 100.  Math.random() returns a number greater than or equal to 0 and less than 1.  When you cast it to an int, 99.9999 would become 99.

If you'd like it to really be 0-100, you would want this:

```
int random = (int)(Math.random() * 101);
```

Also, you probably want the game to terminate after a player wins.  So change this:

```
System.out.println("YOU WIN");
```

to this:

```
System.out.println("YOU WIN");
return;  //end
```

Lastly, your empty else clause is never called.  You have conditions for out of range, greater than random, less than random, and equal to random.  You can safely remove that dead code.

Comment: so "return" ends the program in a if statement?

Comment: return marks the end of the method.  In this case you're in the program's main method, main(), so it will end the program.

Comment: @nostromo how are you? just friendly point did you see this line? if(guess2 >= 100 || guess2 <= 0){ is it between 0 and 100 to you?

Comment: Look, I'm old school, so I was always taught to have one entry and one exit point for all functions/methods.  Instead of whacking a `return` statement below each `win` state, it would be better to have all the logic contained within a loop and `break` to break out of the loop - but that's just me

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 Major Issue with your code:

**First**:

you failed to cast random variable in right away so the value for random value is always 0.

The right style is:

```
int random = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
```

**Second**:

your if structure is terrible:

for example:

```
if(guess >= 100 || guess <= 0){
```

> 1. you said guess is greater and equal 100
> 2. you said guess is less and  equal 0
> 3. you used || operand instead of `&&` to check the number to be in range of 0 and 100

try this :

```
if (guess <= 100 && guess >= 0) {
        if (guess > random) {
            System.out.println("The guess is too high.");
        } else if (guess < random) {
            System.out.println("The guess is too low.");
        } else if (guess == random) {
            System.out.println("YOU WIN");
        }
     } else {
        System.out.println("Error, that is not a number between 0-100.");
    }
```

**Explanation**: if the gussing number is between 100 and 0, do the following. if it is not tell the user that he or she is out of the range.

Comment: So "if" statements should have it defined again at the beginning and then error at the end of the statement? I'm kind of confused as to why 
if(guess <= 100 && guess >= 0) is needed since the programmer already knows this.

Comment: ya I change my code and do you learn about the loop concept in Java?

Comment: well I learned what a while and for loop does, but the teacher never really said anything about how to organize the format.

Comment: oh K if you want I can add some info for you that you can improve your code ?

Comment: @Nocturne how did you accept the answer when you have issues in other parts?

Comment: Yes please, that would be very helpful.

Comment: @Nocturne you have accepted your answer which does not address all your issues, so good luck :)

Comment: While you did find another error in my program while also correcting my answer, I would say that nostromo answered the main problem (the 1 being too high) with a more in-depth explanation.

Answer (score 0):

change `int random = (int)Math.random() * 100;` to `int random = (int)(Math.random() * 100);`

Comment: add some explaintion to your post, this may help others to understand it quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do your code like this. Easily You ca use a for loop

```
    int guess;
    int random = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Try to guess a number between 0-100. You have five chances.");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println("Chance " + (i + 1));
        guess = input.nextInt();
        if (guess >= 100 || guess <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Error, that is not a number between 0-100.");
        } else if (guess > random) {
            System.out.println("The guess is too high.");
        } else if (guess < random) {
            System.out.println("The guess is too low.");
        } else if (guess == random) {
            System.out.println("YOU WIN");
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(random);
```

Comment: Break the loop when you win, otherwise you'll be repeating all the way through the guesses...